# Change Text Animation Direction With FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmbc

```
"drawtext=fontfile="+fontPath+":text="+topText+":fontcolor=#FFFFFF:fontsize=40:box=0:boxcolor=black@0.2:boxborderw=5:x=min(4*(tw\\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-1)))*(tw+10)-tw\\,w/3.5):y=main_h-(text_h*5)
```

With above script I am moving text from left to right and stay in middle and then move back to left.

How can I can animate it from right to left and then move back to right?

Answer (score 1):

```
x=tw-min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-1)))*(tw+10)-tw\,w/3.5)
```

With this script I can animate text from right to left and stay in middle for a second and then go back to right side.